# Tracking custom fields in Adsense

Tags: adsense, adsense-api

I was wondering if it's possible to put a custom field onto an Ad Unit that could be used to filtering an API call, and be used to calculate that content's earnings to allow sharing revenue with the site's content creators.

There are more than 500 content creators and Custom Channels are limited to 500, so they cannot be used. I couldn't find any related question or article about that kind of customization.

Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I asked to the ADSense forum there is no way to add a custom tag to a banner and filtering by an API call. Me too I needed to share revenues with more than 500 publishers. Actually you can do that with the "ADSense Host" plan
https://developers.google.com/adsense/host/
Please note, only websites with over 100k daily page views are eligible to participate in the AdSense Host API program.